# Shouldn't there be a timeout on people's ability to unmark an answer?

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer

I was awarded points for giving an answer on the 1st of Feb.

Today (8th Feb) I login and find that the person has removed my answer flag, so I've lost points.

They have not awarded the points to anybody else, nor have they given any reason in comments for removing my answer flag.

Any ideas ?

Comment: If that person determined your answer no longer best answered the question, why should they be prevented from unaccepting your answer just because of time.

Comment: They should be forced to give a reason for unaccepting the answer.  Otherwise it just opens up the whole answer system to blatant abuse !!!

Comment: Why is it abuse?

Comment: Because this whole site is built on people building reputation by gaining points, primarily by answering questions.  If people are allowed to come along and award and retract points for no reason then the system is open to abuse.

Comment: You still haven;'t explained why it is abuse.  All you have done is say that you are upset that you lost the rep and you want to prevent people from unaccepting answers that cause you to loose rep.

Comment: @psubsee2003, its blatantly obvious why its abuse. Seriously !  Please re-read my point... I'm NOT saying "lock immediately" ... I'm saying lock after a reasonable "cooling-off" period.

Comment: Obviously is not blatantly obvious why it is abuse or I wouldn't be asking you to explain why it is abuse.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but harvesting magical Stack Overflow reputation shouldn't be your primary reason for answering questions. Having a possible answer should be, consider the reputation as a bonus. **Stack Overflow is a question and answer website**.

Comment: @psubsee2003, sorry but you're just being argumentative.  As I explained quite clearly to you.  The whole foundation of this site is based on people earning reputation by answering questions.  People who contribute their time, answering questions, for no financial remuneration, should at  least be given some re-assurance that answers that have sat happily marked as answered for days, months, weeks,years .... CANNOT be suddenly withdrawn at a whim with no reason given.   It opens up the system for abuse, for example, but not limited to, if you've answered one user a few times over the years....

Comment: You've provided no information about why this is *abuse* (or how it *could be abused*) at all. In what way can accepting and then unaccepting an answer be abused? The person asking the question is the one who gets to decide if an answer should be accepted and which answer gets that acceptance. If they later change their mind, it's **still their decision to make**. The *whole foundation of this site* is **sharing knowledge**. It's not about *earning points*, and if you're here just for *earning points* you shouldn't be.

Comment: They could then go back over their entire history, unmark all your quesitions and you'd be with a dent in your points for no valid reason.   But there are many other possible forms of abuse too...

Comment: That's not *abuse*, and there *would* in fact be a valid reason. The person who is responsible for awarding acceptance decided not to award it to you, and that is a **totally valid reason**. It's that person's choice, not yours.

Comment: Don't try to change the system. Instead, ask for clarification from the OP. Ask if they've understood everything you've written and if there's anything missing. If they still don't accept your answer, that's up to them. If your answer is any good (and the question is in any way useful, ie. other people are looking for the same information), you'll gain points over time.

Comment: I've decided to delete my answer to that question instead.  Why should I chase them.  If they don't have the modicum of human decency to leave me a comment as to why they removed something they appeared to be perfectly happy with then I can't be bothered either.    Treat others how you'd like to be treated as they say !

Comment: So your solution to having an accepted answer taken away is to deprive future readers of this site that information? As I said, you're here for totally the wrong reason. You should find a different site completely; you've got the wrong attitude here. You're not here for sharing knowledge or helping people; you're here to try and build your own ego, and we don't need people like that here.Talk about not having a modicum of human decency - you're depriving future readers here a solution to their problem because of your petty need for ego and recognition.

Comment: Let's not throw out the baby with the bathwash here. The best solution is not for you to give up and leave, but instead to readjust your thinking. If you think more of the benefit to the site and less about the points, and if you **apply yourself towards becoming an expert in a subfield of programming** you will find yourself gaining points without thinking about it. The points are just there as a non-legal tender minor motivator, to try to motivate folks to contribute to the site.

Comment: The only thing that they're truly good for is 1) it makes it easy to place bounties on your questions or questions that you find interesting, and 2) if you gain enough points you might get a coffee mug and/or a t-shirt. Big whoop.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Stickers, too.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: ah yes, stickers too.

Comment: You've actually asked fifteen-odd questions on SO to date, and accepted answers for some of them, so presumably you got some benefit out of that. You managed to do that with your rep being in the 100-range so I'm not sure about your claim in a comment to another answer here that "you can hardly do anything on StackOverflow unless you have reputation". I'm curious though what benefit you think I'm getting at 380K that I didn't get at 10K, yet still I answer questions here :-) _And_ ask, that's important as well, this isn't a one-way street for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you appear to have rage-deleted your answer, it's hard to tell _why_ the answer may have been considered deficient. If you'd like to put it _back,_ we could possibly offer advice on how to improve it, if you wish.

Comment: >> you're depriving future readers here a solution to their problem ..... well ken, if I were to take your broad argument throughout this whole thread, according to you, its all my fault that the OP removed the "accepted" status from my answer, because my answer that was acceptable 10 days ago is apparently not good enough any more ... so if according to you I should take it that my answer was suddenly deemed no longer good enough for the OP then obviously it isn't good enough to grace the pages of this site either !

Comment: @LittleCode `I should take it that my answer was suddenly deemed no longer good enough for the OP then obviously it isn't good enough to grace the pages of this site either !` If the only answers worth posting were the ones with a green checkmark next to them, wouldn't we be deleting all other answers automagically? Clearly they have no worth because OP didn't award them the badge of honor. 

Do you really not see how you are missing the point here? We have no idea why the OP removed the accept, and does it even matter? If your answer was helpful it should stay. Period.

Comment: @eddie_cat: I'm wondering if we're wasting our breath here, that he is completely fixated on points to the exclusion of all else.

Comment: @LittleCode: I'm saying that possibly the poster accepted too fast, and then decided it wasn't the appropriate solution *for their situation*. I'm saying it's all your fault that you're depriving future readers here the benefit of your answer just because of a  reaction to losing the accept checkmark, and you're the one missing the point here. **The points are not the reason to be answering here, and if they are you're here for the wrong reasons.** I don't know how to be more clear:- **this site is not about your points - it's about *sharing knowledge with others*, and **nothing else**.

Answer (score 8):

With the way Stack Overflow works, the only way the question asker has to say "this is the best answer to solve my problem" is to check the accepted answer check mark.

So why should there be a limit on the ability of that person to unaccept that answer if they find after any period of time that it no longer solves their problem.

Maybe they accepted your answer initially because it looked like it worked, but after a period of time, they found it didn't work after more testing?  Or maybe they accepted the answer accidentally and didn't realize it until several days after?  Or maybe they felt like they had to accept an answer

Ideally they should leave a comment explaining why, but their is no mechanism that requires them to explain, in the same way that there is no mechanism that requires them to explain why they accepted it in the first place.

---

Ultimately, if you are here to collect rep, then you are not really using Stack Overflow in the way the it is designed.  It does not exist to provide you with reputation.  While there are users that are here only for reputation, most users enjoy participating, with the reputation being a bonus.

In the end, there should never be anything that "protects" reputation because reputation is based on the quality of your answers and the quality is always dynamic.  Why should something that was thought to be "right" 2 months ago always be considered "right" even when it is wrong.

Comment: >Ultimately, if you are here to collect rep, then you are not really using >Stack Overflow in the way the it is designed. ............. please @psubsee2003 ... spare me that nonsense... you know very well you can hardly do anything on StackOverflow unless you have reputation ... its one big catch22 !

Comment: @LittleCode You missed the most important line in this post: the last one. "Why should something that was thought to be "right" 2 months ago always be considered "right" even when it is wrong."

Comment: Kevin.. techology and best practices change.... what might be "right" now, might NOT have been then , hell it might not have even been technologically possible then !   People's answers should be accepted as to what the Question asker deems to be "right" at or around the time they accepted the answer.      A month is a long time in technology...things change and hence legacy answers should be locked.

Comment: @LittleCode that's not what Stack Overflow is about.  It is about being a timeless repository of questions and answers about programming problems.  What value does an answer have if it is outdated?  When something becomes outdatec, the author is under no obligation to change their answer, there should not be a mechanism that prevents it,.